# Git move n commits forward

Tags: git, git-checkout

I'm in commit C (I just did a `git checkout hash_of_C`) of a repository.

```
A - B - C - ...<19>... - D - ...<many many commits> - Z
```

Which Z is the last commit in the master branch

Now, I want to move forward 20 commits.

Comment: In general I guess it's not possible by using "20 commits in the future". It might work only on simplest trees (no merges, no forks, means no branches).

Comment: @0andriy Yeah, if you have to commit hash of the +20 commit, then moving HEAD forward is trivial. But, you are completely right about the "simple trees" part.

Comment: @DarrylLJohnson, yeah, I just recall the term: *linear*. In non-linear cases it's non-trivial task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, you want to move forward 20 commits from C, and Z is the last commit on the master branch but not necessarily the 20th commit from C.

From C do

```
C > git checkout $(git rev-list --topo-order HEAD..master | tail -20 | head -1)
```

It will checkout the 20 commit forward **if it exists.**

I am not totally confident about it but here is what it does.

**git rev-list --topo-order HEAD..master** will give you list of all the commits from C to master/one per line.

```
> ➦ b17c0a7 > git rev-list --topo-order HEAD..master          
3c5b47003a5bc576d6c5d13b065bb70aef28828f
306fee6443d0e2ebb0a5372dfdff0d55728950f3
02acfd4b6987dfc8bc689a18d21ee82ad8132839
```

When we do tail -20 we basically want to cut a piece out of this list from bottom 20 line up. If we do head -1, we cut the list further, taking only the top item. This way we get the 20th item forward from the current commit.

Which is **$(git rev-list --topo-order HEAD..master | tail -20 | head -1)**

Comment: And if you have fork to two branches and then merge them back and there are two `+20` commits in the history. Which one is correct?

Comment: @0andriy Fork to two branches (Fork as in repo ?). The above solution is only correct if someone goes to a detached state from the master branch.

Answer (score 2):

So, you want to move the branch pointer that you are currently on to D?

This can be done a few ways:

1. Using the commit hash for D, `git merge <commit-id>` will move the pointer forward using the fast-forward merge process
2. If there is a branch pointer that points to D (like if D is pointed to by master, develop, etc) then `git merge <branch name>` will move the pointer forward using the fast-forward merge process

The [Git Book - Basic Branching and Merging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) goes into more detail.

Comment: I'm in detached HEAD. I just did a random `git checkout` and I need to move forward from there.

Comment: @ΑναστάσηςΑνδρονίδης to **where**?

Comment: @ΑναστάσηςΑνδρονίδης This depends entirely on your list topology. If your HEAD pointer is currently pointing to C and the topology can be completely described as `A - B - C - ...<19>... - D` then `git reset HEAD --hard <commit-hash-D>` will move the HEAD pointer to D. If you have done some other work and then checked out, different story.

Comment: @0andriy From commit C to +20 commits

Answer (score 0):

> Now, I want to move forward 20 commits.

You simply need to checkout master. since master latest commit it the Z which you want to checkout do this:

```
git checkout master
```

and that it. you will see the latest commit on your master.

#### Update

If commit D was not part of the original branch you can use chery-pick with a commit range to "import" your 20 commits to the repo

You can `cherry-pick` all the commits from one branch to another with the commit range `..`.

```
git cherry-pick <first commit>..<last-commtit>
```

Comment: I think this answer has been downvoted but is actually correct.

Comment: @TheMagician doesnt op need to get to D? But the last commit in master is Z. Unless im missing something, i think itll get op to the wrong commit

Comment: You want get D since D is commited on a detached HEAD since the checkout of C created it so when you checkout master it will not be there unless it was there in first place.

Comment: @jbu My answer is based relative to master branch. Maybe you are right. I still don't completely understand the question op is asking for (my answer is just a guess, hope it's right).

Comment: Your answer might be right buy with cherry-pick its much more simple and clean.

Comment: @TheMagician, guys, had you really understood the question? I don't think so.\