# Git determine latest commit

Tags: git

I have a bash script that iterates (forward in time) through a git repo. I have a `curr_hash` variable that represent the current hash, and I want to end my loop when `curr_hash` is the latest commit (which means that I can't iterate forward in time anymore). How do I do this?

Comment: That's a really really bad way to do it.  Instead, do `git rev-list --all --reverse`, that will get you a timestamp-ordered list of commits, latest last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to move forward on a specific branch (because [you know which branch your current commit is part of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1419637/6309)), you can use [`git rev-list --topo-order`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#Documentation/git-rev-list.txt---topo-order) as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14200660/6309) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41907603/6309).

```
git rev-list --topo-order curr_hash ..<yourBranch>
```

You can then reverse that list, and loop in the proper order.